# How to determine valid strings in a language described by a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am having trouble understanding how to determine a valid string for given regular expressions. I know the answers since an answer key was provided, but there are no explanations and would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain how the following answers are determined:

**Provide a valid string in the languages described by each of the following regular expressions, with alphabet ∑ = {0, 1, 2}.**

(a) 0(010)*1

answer: 01, 00101, 00100101, 00100100100101

(b) (21 ∪ 10)*0012

answer: 001, 001222, 21001, 10001, 210012, 2121001222, 102121001

(c) 1*(200)* ∪ 100*01

answer: 1, 200, 111, 11200200, 111200200200, 1001, 1000001, 10000001

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a maths/computer science question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question is related to the [regular expressions in the formal language theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory), not the regular expressions that are used in software development (the latter are patterns for string search, a real-life software implementation based on the concepts defined in the former).

In your question, a regular expression is a description of a set of strings that *match* this expression. Characters `0`, `1`, and `2` match themselves, while `*` character means that the previous character or group of characters (in parentheses) can be repeated 0 or more times, and `∪` character is a union operator.

Given that, we see that regular expression `0*` matches an empty string and the following strings: `0`, `00`, `000`, etc. Similarly, `(0 ∪ 1)*` matches an empty string, `0`, `1`, `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`, etc. - basically, any string built by `0` and `1`. Regex `01*2` matches all strings that start with one zero, followed by one or more ones, and end with 2 (e.g. `02`, `012`, `0112`, etc).

Based on that, the regular expression in your first example can be translated into English as 'a string that starts with `0`, followed by a group of three digits `010` that occur zero or more times, followed by `1`', so all of the given answers match. In the second example though, only `210012` matches the regular expression, all other answers don't match (or maybe you missed `*` at the end: if the regular expression is `(21 ∪ 10)*0012*` the answers will immediately make more sense). I'll leave the third example for you.

Note that in all three cases, there are many more strings that match the given expressions, not just those given in answers.